# Authentication popup doesn't display in Firefox

Tags: windows-10, firefox, authentication, popups

When I go on a specific website which uses the "authentication required" popup, nothing is displayed and I'm redirected to the main page.

I'm running Firefox 61.0.1(64bits) on Windows 10.

I've tried on a VM under Kali and Firefox 52.9.0 (64bits) and it's working.
So I downloaded this version for Windows but it doesn't work either.
I've tried starting Firefox in safe mode, and still no authent' popup.

Add-ons are not the culprits since it doesn't work in safe mode.

Any ideas ?

Thank you !

Comment: Does it work in Internet Explorer or Edge?

Comment: Yes. It opens the windows style popup asking for authent and it works.

Comment: It may be using NTLM autenication rather than basic http. Are you able to provide a link?

Comment: The website is www.seedbox.fr then I click on a specific link to open rutorrent interface which is at https://proxy.seedbox.fr/v/seedboxxxxxxxxx/web/.

Answer (score 0):

Found it !

I tweaked Firefox for privacy following this site recommandation https://www.privacytools.io/#about_config

The culprit parameter is network.http.referer.XOriginPolicy which must not be set to 2 but only 1.

I had to reset firefox and test each parameter one by one, because restarting firefox in safe mode does not reinitiate the about:config parameters.

Hope it helps.

Thank you @mt025